# "errorMessage": "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'SecretString')"

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services

If you are getting the error `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'SecretString')` while using the `@aws-sdk/client-secrets-manager` then you need to update your code to use the new version.

Comment: If you're implying that there's a bug in the SDK itself then it would be good to indicate the bugged and fixed versions of the SDK, plus a reference to a GitHub issue (if you're aware of one).

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to fix the error:

```
const client = new SecretsManagerClient({
        region: "us-east-1",
    });

    const input = {
        SecretId: secret_name,
        VersionStage: "AWSCURRENT",
    }

    const command = new GetSecretValueCommand(input)

    let response;

    try { 
        response = await client.send(command)
        console.log("response", response)
        return response;
    } catch (error) {
        console.log("err", error)
    }

    let secret;
    if ("SecretString" in response) {
        secret = response.SecretString;
    } else {
        console.log("else", response)
    }
```

Comment: How does this fix the error?